# how to use event triggers in mvvm wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

i would like to raise my event keydown when i am typing something in my textbox my commands will just count how long it tooks to write the input

this my xaml with the textbox :

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Texts.mydata,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontWeight="SemiBold">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding LigneAddCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBlock>
```

in my view model 
here is my relayCommand:

```
private RelayCommand _ligneAddCommand;
public RelayCommand LigneAddCommand => _ligneAddCommand = _ligneAddCommand ?? new RelayCommand(LigneAddKeyDownEventHandle, LignaAddCanBeExecuted);

protected virtual bool LignaAddCanBeExecuted() => true;

protected virtual void LigneAddKeyDownEventHandle()
{
    if (timer != null)
        timer.Stop();

    timer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Tick += (s, args) =>
    {
        //fetch data here...
        timer.Stop();
    };
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50);
    timer.Start();
}
```

my problem when i put my breakpoint in my viewmodel it seems my event is never raised

Comment: Are there any BindingErrors logged in the `Output` window?

Comment: How is the actual command constructed. `LigneAddKeyDownEventHandle` is not used in what we see.

Comment: Why did you post the markup of a `TextBlock`? And how is `LigneAddCommand` defined and what's the `DataContext` of the `TextBox`?

Comment: @prestasoc i've added all the command

Comment: Try `<i:InvokeCommandAction Command=.. CommandParamater=..` instead of `<cmd:EventToCommand`. Or set `PassEventArgsToCommand` to false as you are not passing arguments to command.